# Magento 2 Installation - Key must not exceed 56 bytes

Tags: linux, nginx, installation, magento2

I'm having issues installing Magento 2 via command line. When setup is running it gets to:

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running recurring..

And it throws an error:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>   Key must not exceed 56 bytes.

I have searched around and couldn't find any clues as to what it can be. I thought the --key might be too long for Magento setup but I have tried the setup without --key, as it is optional but the error still occurs.

> 2016/07/08 14:42:49 [error] 30074#30074: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Key must not exceed 56 bytes.' in /magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Crypt.php:58
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->__construct('oon5eeRee7yiemo...', 'blowfish', 'ecb', false)
>
> 1 /magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('oon5eeRee7yiemo...', 0, false)
>
> 2 /magento/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(107): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('PayPal')
>
> 3 /magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config/MetadataProcessor.php(86): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('PayPal')
>
> 4 /magento/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Config/Data.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataPr" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.magentotest.com, request: "GET /setup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.magentotest.com"

If anyone could help that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Please post the command you use to install Magento. As you say, `--key` is optional. If you omit it, we'll generate a key for you.

Comment: @Steve Johnson, here is the command that I am trying to use at the moment, bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="dbm2" --db-user="dbuser" --db-password="dbpass" --language="en_GB" --currency="GBP" --use-secure=0 --base-url="http://www.magentotest.com" --admin-user=admin --admin-password=supersecret --admin-email=john@doe.com --admin-firstname=John --admin-lastname=Doe --cleanup-database

All the data has been substituted for obvious reasons.

Comment: `--base-url` isn't correct but that might not be the cause of the problem. It should be `--base-url=http://magentotest.com/` with the scheme and a slash at the end. Also, I don't use quotation marks around values but again that might not mean anything. I'm not sure what to say; other than those things, your values are very similar to ones I use all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/etc/env.php` is populated with the details of your installation. Look at the contents `crypt`, and make sure that `key` doesn't have multiple lines appended to it, as was the case in my new installation, after running the `setup:install` multiple times.

Changing this key for a current install would obviously be a bad idea. If this fixes you out, please let me know so I can log a ticket.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! That has fixed this issue. I had to remove all attempted keys, which were indeed on multiple lines. Once done the setup went without a hiccup!

Comment: @PRx my self code like this in app/etc/env.php - 'crypt' => [ 'key' => 'admin', ], what to change here